# How to overlay two heatmaps via ggplot2 with two different scales_fill_gradient?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data which has two variables and I want to see a single plot with heatmap for each of them overlaid on one another and showing two color scales for the two different variables. My code while not correct should clearly indicate what I am trying to achieve.

I have looked through several examples none of those indicate how to do this for geom_tile(). It would have been easy for geom_point. I am providing a synthetic example to show what I am doing. I get the error saying "Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale." Evidently it is accepting only the second scale_fill_gradient, but I would like to view both the color gradients corresponding to the variables in the same heatmap. 
It would be great if I could find a way to get this plot. Thank you!

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2)
m1 = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
m2 = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
M1 = melt(m1)
M2 = melt(m2)
names(M1)  = c("Var1", "Var2", "value1")
names(M2)  = c("Var1", "Var2", "value2")
pp1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=M1, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value1)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="red") +
  geom_tile(data=M2, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value2)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="yellow")
pp1
```

Comment: The issue with overlying colors is that the resulting color in a given tile will be different. And that'd be a color different from both color scales. So you'd need a bivariate color legend.

Comment: I'm not familiar with two overlaid heatmaps in practical usage. Do you have examples where it is done, whether "done well" or not? (I'd think, similar to discussions about having multiple y-axes on a plot, it can very easily be confusing so is discouraged and therefore not easily supported.)

Comment: You could do M2$value_1 <- M1$value1 and ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=M2, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value2, alpha = value_1)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(). So the alpha scale is mapped to the alpha aes. But it's confusing

Comment: Consider the channels of an image as separate grayscale images. So I necessarily want to see them as heatmaps to see intensities of the individual channels but overlaid. @r2evans

Comment: @PabloRod I understand your point; mapping to alpha doesn't actually serve my purpose...but thanks!

Comment: While I haven't tried, but I am quite sure this could be elementary in minitab using the holdon command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the legends themselves are no problem with the `ggnewscale` package, the problem lies in choosing the actual colours that you want to display. So let's make a new matrix with the actual colours you want to display:

```
library(ggnewscale)
library(scales)

r <- rescale(M1$value1)
# 1 - rescaled value because yellow should be bottom
g <- 1 - rescale(M2$value2)

# Second scale goes from yellow (low) to blue (high)
# Yellow is 100% blue, 100% green, so blue stays invariant
rgb <- rgb(r, g, 1)

# Make new matrix
M3 <- M1
M3$value1 <- rgb
```

And now plotting would occur as follows:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
  # This bit is for making scales
  geom_tile(data=M1, aes(fill = value1)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data=M2, aes(fill=value2)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="blue") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  # This is the actual colours
  geom_tile(data=M3, aes(fill = M3$value1)) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

The legends aren't 100% accurate since ggplot mixes colours in 'Lab' space, while we've mixed colours in rgb space, but you could replace the `scale_fill_gradient()` with for example `scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rgb(seq(0, 1, length.out = 100), 0, 0))`. Also be aware that the white-to-red scale should technically be a black-to-red scale in this example.

Comment: This works great. I was trying to make it interactive using ggplotly(pp2), pp2 being stored as the plotted object from your code. It provides a bunch of warnings and then plots with a messed up legend. I tried adding theme(legend.position = "none") after geom_tile(data=M3, aes(fill = M3$value1), but that also removes the legends for M1 and M2. Any idea on how to fix that? @teunbrand

Comment: Sorry I've never used anything ggplotly related, I wouldn't know how to backtrace the errors and try to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

A bivariate color legend. The intervals should maybe be the corresponding quantile.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

set.seed(2)
m1 = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
m2 = matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
M1 = melt(m1)
M2 = melt(m2)
names(M1)  = c("Var1", "Var2", "value1")
names(M2)  = c("Var1", "Var2", "value2")

M1$value_cut <- cut(M1$value1, breaks = 3)
M2$value_cut <- cut(M2$value2, breaks = 3)

M1$value_cut2 <- M2$value_cut
M1$cuts <- paste(M1$value_cut, M1$value_cut2, sep = "-")

levels_comb <- expand.grid(lev1 = levels(M1$value_cut), lev2 = levels(M2$value_cut))
levels_comb$cuts <- paste(levels_comb$lev1, levels_comb$lev2, sep = "-")
levels_comb$filling <- c("#be64ac","#8c62aa","#3b4994","#dfb0d6","#a5add3","#5698b9","#e8e8e8","#ace4e4","#5ac8c8")

data_m <- left_join(M1, levels_comb, by = "cuts")

plot_tile <- ggplot(data_m, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = filling)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()

legend_tile <- ggplot(levels_comb, aes(x = lev1, y = lev2, fill = filling)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(plot_tile, 0, 0, 1, 1) +
  draw_plot(legend_tile, .75, .4, .3, .3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find `geom_col() + facet_grid()` to be a useful pattern to get at your goal of visualizing the multiple values from the same area together.

There is a little set-up overhead from your starting data:

```
names(M1)  = c("Var1", "Var2", "value")
names(M2)  = c("Var1", "Var2", "value")
M1$type <- "M1"
M2$type <- "M2"

M <- rbind(M1, M2)
```

But the plot is straight forward. You don't really need the fill scale anymore, but I like to keep for highlighting the value changes.

```
ggplot(M) +
  geom_col(aes(type, value, fill = value)) +
  facet_grid(Var2 ~ Var1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="yellow")
```

[image]

Not sure if this is palatable for you or not, but at least you get to see an alternative viz option.

Comment: Thanks @Nate, this helps when I am looking at a small image or a smaller section of a larger image!